# Getting data from MySQL database thats usable for functions

Tags: php, mysql, function, if-statement

I created a function that is able to print information on screen. However I cannot use this function to store this data in an $variable. I'm also not able to call this into the if comparator (it directly prints it on screen).

Here is an example how i would store the data:

```
$usertype = getusertype();
or using it in an if statement:
if(getusertype==1){
something}
```

Here is my function

```
function getusertype() {

    global $con;
    /* getting the needed data for the query */

    $myusername = $_SESSION['myusername'];
    /* defining the query */

    $sql3 = "SELECT usertype FROM person WHERE person_id='$myusername'";

    if ($result = mysqli_query($con,$sql3)) {

        /* fetch object array */
         while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
            printf ("%s  ", $row[0]);
        }

        /* free result set */
        $result->close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning value from your function.

Rather you are printing it, so, its not working.

Instead of

```
printf ("%s  ", $row[0]);
```

Do:

```
return $row[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `If` instead of while and `return $row[0];` instead of printf